# secure my program from RE

Tags: c++, security, authentication

I create a Program, and I want to make a Rent option, and need secure it from RE,
I want that a user that rent the Program I created will have any authentication that even if the User Reverse it, the software wont work,

What should I do? What should I add? 
Looking for suggestions to how secure my program that will have the option to rent

edit: 
change it from c# to c++
It possible?

edit2:

I see it not possible, What can I do to make the RE harder?

I have website that i can use to authentication.

Comment: @JameyD ok and if i will build the same software in c++ ( i can do it )

Comment: Same rules apply, if you're talking about unmanaged C++ then it'll somewhat more difficult but still doable. Eventually, the assembly has to be executed by the CPU, this means that that assembly is also visible for the computer user.

Comment: @JameyD if i cant protect from RE but i can protect that the program wont  work if the authentication failed even if the user change the assembly of the code?
I mean If i do authentication with website(i have) and it failed it wont work.

cause i know if someone that know RE can do NOP or change the condition of the software. what you suggest me to do?

Comment: No, they can just take out the "not working" part of the code and make it work even if auth fails. The only resort you have is using reflection to literally send code on the fly from server to client upon successfull auth. This is not a good way to do it though.

Comment: @JameyD so how i can make to hard the RE for the person?

Comment: The only way to stop users seeing the code they're using is not to give them code, ie run part or all of the application on your own servers and charge for access. Forget about solving the Copy Protection Problem - bigger, cleverer companies than you have been trying to do it for decades and it always fails.

Comment: BTW, I suggest refraining from abbreviations.  The term *RE* also has the meaning **R**egular **E**xpression which is common among programmers.  If you can spell out *authentication*, you can spell out *reverse engineer*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common desire. First and foremost, understand that you can never truly make a program that cannot be reverse engineered. Most "anti-reverse engineering" techniques are aimed at making the job of a reverse engineer harder, and are likely only going to be very effective against amateurs. I'll list two popular techniques I've been exposed to from reverse engineering malware. This is a field of reverse engineering that likely sees some of the most sophistication in anti-RE methods as malware authors are constantly improving techniques to make their original code less accessible and less readable.

1. Anti-debugging & Anti-disassemblers. This involves including code in your program that will cause known (common) debugging or disassembling software to either malfunction or crash if the program is run through them. OR the ability to prevent code from running, disabling itself, or even crashing the OS if a disassembler or debugger is found to be installed on the machine when the program is run. See: [IsDebuggerPresent function (msdn)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), ["Stack Necromancy: Defeating Debuggers By Raising the Dead"](http://spareclockcycles.org/2012/02/14/stack-necromancy-defeating-debuggers-by-raising-the-dead/), and ["Anti-Disassembly techniques used by malware (a primer)"](http://malwinator.com/anti-disassembly-used-in-malware-a-primer/).
2. Code obscurity. This involves writing the original code in confusing and distracting ways ([spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)) to make it difficult to determine the intent and behavior of the program. Keep in mind this could backfire if implemented incorrectly as making your code difficult to make heads or tails of will obviously affect both parties. See: ["Obfuscation (software)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29) and ["Cryptographic obfuscation and 'unhackable' software"](http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2014/02/cryptographic-obfuscation-and.html).

For an actual implementation guide of these techniques, see: ["An Anti-Reverse Engineering Guide"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30815/An-Anti-Reverse-Engineering-Guide).

Please keep in mind however that using anti-RE techniques on legitimate software (although sadly common) is a bad security practice and is frowned upon by the security community. Not to mention that if something is hard to break into, it typically presents itself as a challenge. See: ["Security through obscurity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and ["Hacker ethic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_ethic).

Comment: Thank you didnt know that functions like that, gonna use it